# Compile only css modules with webpack, not javascript

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, css-modules

Is there a way to compile css modules in a webpack build but not compile the javascript at all? I want to publish a react component that uses css-modules, but point to my source files as the entry point (un-transpiled javascript). However, if I don't compile the css-modules, the people that consume that component won't be able to use it unless they are also using css-modules loaders. Is something like this even possible in webpack, or is there some library which exists that does this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can utilize the [null-loader](https://github.com/webpack/null-loader) for your JavaScript.  The `loader` portion of your config should look something like this.

```
{
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "null-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        ]

    }
};
```